redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage. in NextJS/App Router
I'm trying to set up a simlpe Redux store in my NextJS 14/Typescript web app with persistent data. Here's what I have so far from following official doc, and a few blogs here and there.
provider.tsx
"use client";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { makeStore, AppStore } from "./redux/store";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

export default function StoreProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }
  const persistedStore = persistStore(storeRef.current);

  return (
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistedStore}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

counterSlice.ts
// store/slices/counterSlice.ts
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

interface CounterState {
  value: number;
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0,
};

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
        console.log("a")
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;

and finally my layour.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Providers from './provider';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
          <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The problem I'm getting is that when I start up my application with npm run dev, it starts correctly but I'm met with this message: redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage. How do I fix this?
